# node-red raspberry pi multiple input

Tags: raspberry-pi, node-red, gpio

i tryed raspberry pi gpio led control

"A" led is turned on when the "A" switch is pressed. →success

"B" led is turned on when the "B" switch is pressed. →success

If the "A" and "B" switches are simultaneously pressed, the "C" lead is turned on .→fail...

somebody help me

[image: picture]

[{"id":"79f3f425.14b44c","type":"rpi-gpio out","z":"fb042b83.1102b8","name":"","pin":"37","set":"","level":"0","freq":"","out":"out","x":540,"y":180,"wires":[]},{"id":"ac4a24f8.a35c18","type":"rpi-gpio out","z":"fb042b83.1102b8","name":"","pin":"35","set":"","level":"0","freq":"","out":"out","x":540,"y":335,"wires":[]},{"id":"ebb19616.65ca18","type":"rpi-gpio out","z":"fb042b83.1102b8","name":"","pin":"33","set":"","level":"0","freq":"","out":"out","x":540,"y":475,"wires":[]},{"id":"b884dc9d.f5d9e","type":"rpi-gpio in","z":"fb042b83.1102b8","name":"","pin":"31","intype":"tri","debounce":"25","read":false,"x":530,"y":120,"wires":[["3198b12c.e5389e","79f3f425.14b44c"]]},{"id":"3f3426d3.a9a31a","type":"rpi-gpio in","z":"fb042b83.1102b8","name":"","pin":"29","intype":"tri","debounce":"25","read":false,"x":530,"y":280,"wires":[["aca97f17.b4c5","ac4a24f8.a35c18"]]},{"id":"ed65ff1f.ab887","type":"rpi-gpio in","z":"fb042b83.1102b8","name":"","pin":"23","intype":"tri","debounce":"25","read":false,"x":530,"y":420,"wires":[["ab623e01.f8393","ebb19616.65ca18"]]}]

Comment: How do you wire the LEDs, please provide the circuit diagram and your node-RED flow. No one can help you without those information.

Comment: That photo really doesn't help, please draw a proper circuit diagram

Comment: Can't figure out what exactly the connection is because your picture only shown partial connectivity. Your Node-RED flow is basically have three connections, pin31 to pin37, pin25 to pin 35,  pin23 to 33. What are the pins connect to switch A,B,C respectively? What are the pins that LEDs connected to?